# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, nonetype

I am trying to make a program that will play sounds on a button press.  But i am having a trouble calling a function.  What I want to do is click on the LowC (or any other note) button and it goes to the LowC (or its respective note function) and then goes to the function Launch to initiate the sound.  Instead, it gives me the 'Nonetype' error.  I do not know what is wrong.  I've tried replacing this.Launch() with this. Launch, but then it doesn't execute the Launch function as well as I have tried this.Launch(this), but then it still doesn't work.  Any help?

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound
import msvcrt as m

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(this, master):
        Frame.__init__(this, master)
        this.grid()
        this.create()


    def create(this):
        test = m.kbhit()
        if test == True:
            print('test is true')
        this.sound1 = IntVar()
        this.dir = Label(this, text = "Click a button to play a sound")
        this.dir.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W)

        #Create buttons for Notes
        this.LowC = Button(this,
                           text = "Low C",
                           command = this.LowC,
                           ).grid()
        this.D = Button(this,
                           text = "D",
                           command = this.D,
                           ).grid()
        this.E = Button(this,
                           text = "E",
                           command = this.E,
                           ).grid()
        this.F = Button(this,
                           text = "F",
                           command = this.F,
                           ).grid()
        this.G = Button(this,
                           text = "G",
                           command = this.G,
                           ).grid()

        #create launch button
        this.Launch = Button(this,
                           text = "Launch",
                           command = this.Launch,
                           ).grid()

        #create sound length slider
        this.TIME = Scale(this,
                          orient = HORIZONTAL,
                          length = 400,
                          width = 20,
                          sliderlength = 10,
                          from_=0,
                          to = 5000,
                          tickinterval = 500,
                          variable = this.sound1 
                          ).grid()
        #Keypress



    #create freq conversion
    def LowC(this):
        this.freq = 262
        print(this.freq)
        this.Launch()


    def D(this):
        this.freq = 294
        print(this.freq)

    def E(this):
        this.freq = 330
        print(this.freq)

    def F(this):
        this.freq = 349
        print(this.freq)

    def G(this):
        this.freq = 392
        print(this.freq)

    #initiate beep
    def Launch(this):
        winsound.Beep(this.freq, this.sound1.get())
        print('Tada!')
        return


base = Tk()
base.title("Basic Program Outline")
base.geometry("500x500")

app = Application(base)

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: You'll have to include the *full traceback* of your exception.

Comment: Your use of `this` as the first argument for methods is technically fine, but note that the vast majority of Python code uses `self` for that parameter.

Comment: You have both a class method `Launch` and a instance attribute `Launch`. The latter masks the former, you cannot have both. The same applies to your `LowC` method and button.

Comment: There's no need to edit your question once it has been solved. In fact, it's better if you *don't* edit it, if the solution is contained in one of the answers. Just *accept* the answer that solved your problem by clicking its checkmark.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. I'm just used to other forums where they want you to write solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both an attribute and a method named `LowC`.

```
this.LowC = Button(this,
                   text = "Low C",
                   command = this.LowC,
                   ).grid()
...

#create freq conversion
def LowC(this):
    this.freq = 262
    print(this.freq)
    this.Launch()
```

You should rename one of them.

By the way, if you do `self.some_name = Button(args).grid()`, then `self.some_name` will be `None`, because you're assigning the result of `grid` to the variable, not the `Button` instance that you want.

Comment: Same for `Launch` and the letter buttons.

Comment: I was still working out how that could lead to a `TypeError: 'NoneType' is not callable` exception however.

Comment: Ah, yes, the chained `.grid()` call.

Comment: If he added () to the this.Launch in the #create launch button, it would call the method, as it is it calls does nothing when you press LowC

Comment: Upon further investigation, the only attribute that _has_ to be renamed is `Launch`. All the other buttons point to their correct respective methods, in spite of the naming collision. `Launch` is special because it's actually called in `LowC`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the speedy and useful help!  I went through and renamed all the buttons to this.(Note)B as well as this.LaunchB so they do not conflict with the methods like you guys said!  And now it works! :D

Comment: @user3653827, Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)